# Java library for parsing regexes into an AST?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, metaprogramming

Normally, people would use regexes to parse something *else* into an AST. What I'm looking for is a tool that I can use to parse the regex itself into an AST, which I can then manipulate symbolically. Let's say I have a regex like

```
(c(o)w)/(.*?)/omg
```

I want to be able to ask questions like

- How many capturing groups are there?
- Are there are nested groups?
- Is the character `.`, 10th character in the regex, at the start of a capturing group?

And be able to manipulate the regex in some meaningful way, e.g:

- Get the names of all named groups
- Replace all named groups with un-named groups
- Flatten any nested groups into their outer-most enclosing group

before serializing it back into a string.

I've poked around `java.util.regex.Pattern`, but it's internals are all private, so I don't have access to them. Are there any third party libraries which I can use to do this?

Comment: No, you should NEVER use a regexp to "parse" anything but the simplest regular grammars. They are called "regular expressions" for a reason.

Comment: Nobody asked for a regexp to "parse" something. What are you talking about?

Comment: I see, I did not read your question thoroughly. You want to parse regexps, not parse with regexps. Unlikely you'll find a ready to use library, but it should be trivial to implement your own.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to that conclusion myself. I don't think it'll be *trivial* to do it on my own, but it looks like that's the way forward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my ANTLR based PCRE parser: https://github.com/bkiers/PCREParser

Answer (score 4):

I would use [ANTLR](http://antlr.org) to create a lexer/parser for regular expressions. Depending on how much of regular expression syntax you want to use, this may be easy to fairly complex. Antlr comes with a nice graphical editor where you can test the grammar file you are creating. The resulting AST is very easy to manipulate in a standard Java program. If you are new to Antlr, I would highly recommend the Antlr book by Terence.

Comment: You could also mention about ANTLR plugin for Eclipse http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net. Very good recommendation (+1)

Comment: I've considered using ANTLR; I'm using Scala, so I also have the parser-combinator library available. My first choice would be some already made library though (if it exists!), since I hope to avoid becoming an expert in the intricacies regex grammar to do basic manipulation.